# Obtaining a referring short URL using a widget

Tags: javascript, web, url-rewriting, widget, short-url

I'd like to create a client-side javascript widget on a blog that obtains the shortened URL from which a visitor used to come to the blog. While the widget can get the Referrer, such would only be the referring page URL, not the shortened URL that was placed on the site that had to be clicked. I know shortener sites use either 301 or 302 redirects: so is the shortened URL available in the header and then accessible to the browser and subsequently a widget? Do browsers store suck click information accessible via javascript? Is it possible to access off-site shortened URLs in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling history.previous from js will show the tiny url, I'm not sure.

Comment: Nothing showing in firebug, but would have to test further. thx.